# Are sibling substitutions combined in tagged templates?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, tagged-templates

Take into consideration the following:

```
String.raw`Test ${123}${'abc'}`;
String.raw`Test ${123 + 'abc'}`;
```

Is `${123}${'abc'}` equivalent to `${123 + 'abc'}`? In other words, are ciblings converted to the `${123 + 'abc'}` format behind the scenes?

Also, how would someone handle this specific case in their own tagged template function?

Comment: No, they are passed as two separate arguments to the template tag, with an empty string between them. Depending on the tag, the outcome might be the same of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `String.raw`, the behavior is essentially the same. Both it and `+` (with a string value) perform concatenation, achieving the same result.

---

The difference between them is that the 1st line is deferring the concatenation for `String.raw` to perform, with `${123}` and `${'abc'}` provided to it as separate arguments.

In using `+`, the concatenation is always performed upfront, passing only a single value to `String.raw` for `${123 + 'abc'}`.

```
function foo(template, ...values) {
  console.log(template, values);
}

foo`Test ${123}${'abc'}`; // [ 'Test ', '', '' ] [ 123, 'abc' ]
foo`Test ${123 + 'abc'}`; // [ 'Test ', '' ]     [ '123abc' ]
```

With other tagged functions, the difference may be more apparent, as the function may perform other operations before (or besides) concatenation.

A contrived example:

```
// adds 99999 to each value
function bar(template, ...values) {
  var raw = template.raw;
  var result = raw[0];

  values.forEach((value, i) => {
     result += value + 99999;
     result += raw[i + 1];
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(bar`Test ${123}${'abc'}`); // 100122abc9999
console.log(bar`Test ${123 + 'abc'}`); // 123abc99999
```

Comment: Using `+` will also process the values from `.valueOf()` whereas the template substitution method uses `.toString()`. Not different for this case, but very important in the general case.